# how to remote control windows from linux without close the session

Tags: windows, linux, x11, rdp

I am coding on my laptop, and watching online video on an windows pc. the suck video site can't turn to fullscreen mode back after goto next video, so I want to use laptop(linux) to remote control the windows.

But... when I using rdesktop login to the windows, the current session was logout, ...

So , what can I do, is there any client could do this, but I hate kde/gnome/xfce dependencies, I am use awesome wm, and without any above wm and library installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds more like a superuser.com question, but anyway...

Install a VNC client on your Linux box and a VNC server on your Windows box. VNC shares a running session, rather than kicking it off. Otherwise, it is very similar to Remote Desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I use [teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use logmein.com.

Edited to reflect the comment below.